# how to download particular reports in obiee after checking the results page by the client

Tags: dashboard, obiee

client wants to download a particular report after checking the dashboard how to do it?

```
client wants to download a particular report after checking the dashboard how to do it?
```

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the "Export" button of the analysis embedded on that dashboard page.